# set env variables for all the users is not working in docker

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift

I am setting env variable in dockerfile which is not reflecting for all the users when i start the deployment. Unless i go to the terminal and do source /etc/profile.d/ip.sh then only it gets affected to the user. Without doing this activity can we set this value to all the users. If yes how do we need to achieve it.

Created shell script and added in `/etc/profile.d/ip.sh`:

```
IP="1.1.1.1"
export IPADDR=$IP
```

Dockerfile:

```
COPY ip.sh /etc/profile.d
RUN chmod 644 /etc/profile.d/ip.sh
RUN . ./etc/profile.d/ip.sh
```

Comment: Is this the complete dockerfile?

Comment: No.. I just added the commands which i used in the docker file

Comment: I am just wondering if `/tmp/ip.sh` in your local machine, or already exists/created in the image itself?

Comment: basically i have created script in the local and copied that to /etc/profile.d as part of the image creation.

Comment: Well you should use `COPY ip.sh /etc/profile.d/` for copying instead. `RUN` gets executed inside the container during the build.

Comment: Ok thanks for correcting me, Let me do that change and try it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226919/discussion-between-user1485267-and-elgarni).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read the [environment variables section](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) of the docker manual
the reason you should not get what you want is that Docker does not behave the same as full OS therefore you do not get the scripts at startup.

here are some examples from there:

- Set environment variables in containers

  You can set environment variables in a service’s containers with the ‘environment’ key, just like with docker run -e VARIABLE=VALUE ...:

```
web:
  environment:
    - DEBUG=1
```

- The “env_file” configuration option
  You can pass multiple environment variables from an external file through to a service’s containers with the ‘env_file’ option, just like with docker run --env-file=FILE ...:

```
web:
  env_file:
    - web-variables.env
```

- The “.env” file
  You can set default values for any environment variables referenced in the Compose file, or used to configure Compose, in an environment file named .env:

```
$ cat .env
TAG=v1.5

$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: "webapp:${TAG}"
```

Comment: My problem is i want to set an environment variable and use that environment variable in the deployment config and start the pod. Is this possible

Comment: When i set the environment variable at container level. When i open the new terminal the variable which is set is showing as blank.

Comment: @user1485267 take a look at the last option I cited from the docs

Comment: I don't see any option to use env_file in kubernetes

Comment: I did it like below echo "IP=1.1.1.1" > /tmp/ip.env. Now how do we use this value in kubernetes deployment

Comment: In case if i do export echo "IP=1.1.1.1" > /tmp/ip.env and source /tmp/ip.env in dockerentrypoint.. It is applicable only to that session not across all the users/sessions

Comment: you cannot change already running sessions on the fly